# python, for is not working

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm trying to print the spelling alphabet for every single character in the `lst` list and 0 for anything else in the list. My code is as follows :

```
def alphabet(lst):
    returned = []
    for value in lst:
        value = str(value)
        if value == "a":
            returned = returned + ["alpha"]
        elif value == "b":
            returned = returned + ["bravo"]
        elif value == "c":
            returned = returned + ["charlie"]
        #
        # lots of elifs removed here for brevity
        #
        elif value == "y":
            returned = returned + ["yankee"]
        elif value == "z":
            returned = returned + ["zulu"]
        else: 
            returned = returned + ["0"]
    return returned
```

The output given by this function is always `["0"]` for every input. Why the `for`  construct doesn't work for every item on the list? How can I put the `return` statement out of the `for` loop without having an indentation error?

Comment: Show us a sample value for `lst`.

Comment: I think you're calling it wrong, because calling it like `alphabet('something')` works for me. Maybe you're calling it like `alphabet(['something'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should be working correctly if you pass a string to it (i.e. if you do `lst = "test"`, then you get `["tango", "echo", "sierra", "tango"]`). So your problem most likely lies with what you're actually passing to your function. If you pass an actual list, you'll get (unless that list looks like `["t", "e", "s", "t"]`) only `["0"]` as output.

That said, the line

```
str(value)
```

does nothing since you're not assigning the result back to `value`. If you wanted to convert objects of a different type to strings, you would need to do

```
value = str(value)
```

but most likely you don't really want to convert objects of different types - you're working with strings, right (in which case, calling the parameter `lst` is kind of counter-intuitive)?

The most obvious problem, though, is that you should be using a dictionary instead of such a long `if/elif/else` construction.

Something like

```
def alphabet(word):
   """Expects a string "word" and returns a list containing the phonetic alphabet's
      mnemonic for each letter or "0" if the current character can't be converted."""
   alpha = {"a": "alpha", "b": "bravo", ...} 
   return [alpha.get(character, "0") for character in word]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't know python very well, and I don't know what is a dictionary. Do you know how can I put the "return" out of the "for" without having an indentation error?

Comment: Dictionaries are probably the most powerful data structure available in Python. You definitely need to [read the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) right now - don't make your life miserable because you don't know the fundamental data types. In your code sample, the `return` statement appears to be indented correctly; is your editor mixing tabs and spaces by any chance?

Comment: You should also [read the tutorial on lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) (heck, read the entire tutorial, it's worth your time!) - if you want to add items to a list, the pythonic way is to do `returned.append("zulu")` instead of `returned = returned + ["zulu"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, the error was in the str(value) as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the possible mistake you may have done in your code, I would like to suggest you to use a map/dictionary:

```
def alphabet(lst):
    letter2alpha = dict()
    letter2alpha['a'] = "alpha"
    letter2alpha['b'] = "bravo"
    letter2alpha['c'] = "charlie"
    ...
    for l in lst:
       print(letter2alpha.get(l,"Unknown"))
```

You could also fill letter2alpha map as Tim suggested in the answer above (`{"a":"alpha", ...}`) the data structure is the same. The idea is to move the information which relates each letter to its spelling alphabet entry from code control structures to a dynamic data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't know python very well, and I don't know what is a map or a dictionary. Do you know how can I put the "return" out of the "for" without having an indentation error?

Comment: @Sonio Your return is already out of the for as it is indented at the same leven than the 'for' keyword. Nevertheless, returning anything does not have any sense here. Your function is function a procedure with side effects (print). If you want to return something you have to follow the advise given by Tim. If not, remove the `return` statement.